# Sound blocked by flash

Tags: linux, audio, flash, flash-player

I use Debian 64-bit and usually multiple sound generating programs work simultanously. E.g. I start VLC and Firefox (with flash plugin), and I can play sounds in both programs simultanously.

But there is one exception: The standalone flash player (debugger).

When I start that one first, only sounds there work, and no other program can play something.

On the other hand, if I start another program first (e.g. VLC) and then the standalone flash, the sound also works in both.

Is there a way to prevent it from blocking the sound?

Comment: I still have not been able to prevent this from happening. Although  `killall -9 pulseaudio` seems to be sufficient to reenable the sound without needing to kill flash

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the following in your `/etc/asound.conf`: [(source)](http://www.mygnu.de/index.php/2010/09/pulseaudio-flash-blocks-the-audio-device/)

```
pcm.pulse {
    type pulse
}
ctl.pulse {
    type pulse
}
pcm.!default {
    type pulse
}
ctl.!default {
    type pulse
}
```

Then run `sudo alsactl restore` to reload the config file and kill Flash:

I had this problem with the Firefox plugin and just adding the pcm blocks solved it for me. The ctl blocks just messed up some other sound-related things for me but they were in the source so maybe it's helpful in some cases.

Comment: Did not work :( It even made it worse by permanently blocking the sound in everything that is not flash, even if flash is not running